# PHP While Loops from Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have a table that contains members names and a field with multiple ID numbers.  I want to create a query that returns results where any values in the ID fields overlap with any values in the array.

For example: **lastname:** Smith
             **firstname:** John
             **id:** 101, 103

I have Array #1 with the values 101, 102, 103

I want the query to output all members who have the values 101 or 102 or 103 listed in their id field with multiple ids listed.

```
Array (  [0] => 101
         [1] => 102 
         [2] => 103 )

$sql="SELECT firstname, lastname, id
      FROM members WHERE id LIKE '%".$array_num_1."%'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $rows['lastname'].', '.$rows['firstname'].'-'.$rows['id'];
      }
```

I tried to simplify it.  The IDs are actually stored in another table, and I have generated the array from this table.

```
$array_num_1 = array();
$sql_id="SELECT id FROM id_table WHERE id < 200";
$result_id=mysql_query($sql_id);
while($rows_id=mysql_fetch_array($result_id)){;
      $array_num_1[] = $rows_id['id'];
}
```

Comment: Storing a list of values and then trying to write a query against it is a *terrible* way of modeling a relationship. My advice is to use your database as a database. Create a child table for the relationship and then it's trivial to query.

Comment: The IDs actually are stored in a separate table.  See edit above.

Comment: So, you must get rid of these id's in the members table

Comment: Please post exact structure of both tables.

Comment: **Members Table:**
lastname, firstname, id

**ID table:**
id, id_name

For example, a user makes a selection that they want to display all members and the id names who have IDs less than 200 associated with their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize your database. 
Make these ids into separate table.

Edit: And **then** use answers below

Comment: The IDs actually are stored in a separate table.  See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id FROM members WHER id IN (" . implode(', ', $array) . ")"
```

As @cletus says in his comment, though, the database is made for this sort of thing. Hard coding it in an array seems like the suboptimal way of doing things.

Comment: I have tried using the IN function, the problem with this is that there are multiple numbers listed in the ID field.  So WHERE id equals "101, 103" does not work with IN (101, 102, 103)

Comment: Time to fix your database structure, then.

Comment: The IDs actually are stored in a separate table.  See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `IN`:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, id FROM members WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Of course, you could create `(1, 2, 3)` dynamically, e.g. using implode.

---

Whoops, I just realized that I got your db schema wrong. As others have advised, you should normalize it.

Comment: What does 'normalize' it mean?  I am semi-new to this.

Comment: @middus (OT) now where did I see that picture of yours lately? ;)

Comment: @Gordon It's always interesting to see what people here are up to. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, m.id 
FROM members m, id_table i ON m.id=id_name 
WHERE i.id < 200
```